# DBCC REINDEX after an update on a table

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am accessing table with a simple update query, however it gave me this error:

> Error  : Index id 3 on table id 128716480 cannot be used in the optimization of a query as it is >SUSPECT. Please have the SA run DBCC REINDEX on the specified table.

Will running DBCC REINDEX do the trick ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Running that will rebuild the tables indexes.  The only time that may not work is if you are dealing with system tables/system indexes.